# Appending Entire Column into Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm working with a dataframe. If the column in the dataframe has a certain percentage of blanks I want to append that column into a dictionary (and eventually turn that dictionary into a new dataframe).

```
features = {}
percent_is_blank = 0.4


for column in df: 
    x = df[column].isna().mean()
    if x < percent_is_blank:
        features[column] = ??

new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([features], columns=features.keys())
```

What would go in the "??"

Comment: I think `df[column]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think better is filtering with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
new_df = df.loc[:, df.isna().mean()  < percent_is_blank]
```

In your solution is possible use:

```
for column in df: 
    x = df[column].isna().mean()
    if x < percent_is_blank:
        features[column] = df[column]
```